# vlcj giving error after running this code

Tags: java, vlcj

i am working on vlcj trying to run video stream and this the code i used from this tutorial any idea how to fix this issue in the video he got the *vlcliber* path using *JFilechooser*
but i change it to set the path directly

[lectur video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=orMgNh0o38A)

the first class

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package video;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;


/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
public class start {
    private static final JFileChooser ourFileSelector = new JFileChooser();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String vlcPath="C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC";
        String mediaPath="";
        File ourFile;


        ourFileSelector.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        ourFileSelector.showSaveDialog(null);
        ourFile = ourFileSelector.getSelectedFile();
        mediaPath = ourFile.getAbsolutePath();
        new Tutorial2A(vlcPath,mediaPath).run();
    }
}
```

the second class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package video;

/**
 *
 * @author isslam
 */
import com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaListPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent;
import uk.co.caprica.vlcj.runtime.RuntimeUtil;

    public class Tutorial2A {
        private final JFrame ourFrame = new JFrame();
        private final EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent ourMediaPlayer;
        private String mediaPath="";



        Tutorial2A(String vlcPath,String mediaURL){
        this.mediaPath = mediaURL;
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(),vlcPath);
        ourMediaPlayer = new EmbeddedMediaListPlayerComponent();
        ourFrame.setContentPane(ourMediaPlayer);
        ourFrame.setSize(500, 500);
        ourFrame.setVisible(true);
        ourFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        }
        public void run(){
        ourMediaPlayer.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mediaPath);
        }
    }
```

error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialise libvlc.

This is most often caused either by an invalid vlc option begin passed when creating a MediaPlayerFactory or by libvlc being unable to locate the required plugins.

If libvlc is unable to locate the required plugins the instructions below may help:

In the text below <libvlc-path> represents the name of the directory containing "libvlc.dll" and "libvlccore.dll" and <plugins-path> represents the name of the directory containing the vlc plugins...

For libvlc to function correctly the vlc plugins must be available, there are a number of different ways to achieve this:
 1. Make sure the plugins are installed in the "<libvlc-path>/plugins" directory, this should be the case with a normal vlc installation.
 2. Set the VLC_PLUGIN_PATH operating system environment variable to point to "<plugins-path>".

More information may be available in the log, specify -Dvlcj.log=DEBUG on the command-line when starting your application.


    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory.<init>(MediaPlayerFactory.java:279)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.MediaPlayerFactory.<init>(MediaPlayerFactory.java:236)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.onGetMediaPlayerFactory(EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.java:278)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.<init>(EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent.java:168)
    at uk.co.caprica.vlcj.component.EmbeddedMediaListPlayerComponent.<init>(EmbeddedMediaListPlayerComponent.java:50)
    at video.Tutorial2A.<init>(Tutorial2A.java:29)
    at video.start.main(start.java:30)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 19 seconds)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using vlcj 3.0.0, then that version of vlcj depends on version 4.0.0 of JNA.

Unfortunately the combination of LibVLC and JNA 4.0.0 on Windows exposes a new bug [1].

The only solutions available to you right now on Windows are either:

1. Set the VLC_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable (*not* Java system property) to point to the directory that contains the vlc plugins, e.g. "c:\program files\videolan\vlc\plugins"
2. Make sure when you run your Java program that the current directory is "c:\program files\videolan\vlc".
3. Use version 3.5.2 of the JNA and Platform jars instead of 4.0.0.

Obviously you replace the directory strings above with the whatever is appropriate on your own disk.

None of those solutions are ideal.

[1] https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/226

Comment: Thank you so much for the info. I'm totally new to vlcj and tried to use 3.10.1 version. After having changed JNA version to 3.5.2, vlcj started finally working (vlcj version unchanged). :)